# How many requests per second does your live-right-now LAMP server handle?

Tags: lamp

I've had newrelic setup for about a week now, and its giving me interesting new numbers, but I want to compare them to what others are getting.   If you don't have newrelic you can also get these numbers from various cacti or munin type graphs.

My current cluster is made up of dell M610 blades with two L5520 cpu's each.  The individual apache servers do about 200 req/s on a normal day, but have gone as high as 260 req/s.

Anyone got numbers substantially higher or lower?   Preferably just the apache/php part, not any front end http servers or with mysql running on the same server.

Also open to hear nginx/php setup numbers on similar hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get around 400 rps from a LAMP setup on a Core i7 CPU w/8 virtual cores (4 real). Your numbers look good enough for me. I also tested Apache/mod_php vs nginx/php (php-fpm/php actually, since nginx was just a FastCGI proxy) and I got no real difference in performance (that was expected).

Comment: cool thanks, was that your live application or a benchmark of some sort?

Comment: That was a real application being load tested by a synthetic load test pattern

Answer (score 1):

I see 570 rpm in the last 30 minutes (using the free trial now), which is what the Throughput chart shows (are you sure you meant reqs/second?).

**Update**:

Now I can see ~ **1600** rpm on NewRelic's overview for the last 30 minutes.
The setup is LLMP (Lighttpd instead of Apache) ;-)

Comment: Apache, which is what was specified by the poster, does not have any such thing as a "free trial".

Comment: The poster mentions he's "had newrelic setup for about a week now", which has a [free trial](http://newrelic.com/) or, to be more accurate, has a free Lite version which limits the historical charts to the last 30 minutes only.

Comment: yea they do 10 - 12K RPM each, I've feature-requested newrelic let me change the display to RPS but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: 12K RPM.. OK.. my server is a toy then :D